# Using SendKeys to move windows through a batch script

Tags: windows, keyboard, batch

I am trying to learn how to script on Windows 10. I thought a good first project would be a startup script for my work computer. Basically, I have a .bat that starts all the webpages I use regularly and Outlook for my email. This script works fine, but I am having issues using SendKeys to move the windows to the monitors I want and maximizing them. I am currently using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file) to access SendKeys, but it will not let me use ALT and several other keys. For example, if I type `%SendKeys% "^{ESC}"` it will not simulate pushing the windows key. If I do `%{F4}`, it does not close the window. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I applaud ambition, but, if you're trying to learn how to script on Windows, SendKeys might be a bit too ambitious for a first project.

Comment: Thank you for responding! That is the impression I have been getting. Like, I can type stuff through SendKeys, but nothing else it seems.

Comment: @AH I need to ask, really...Are you automating Windows operations in cmd batches? Kudos! Never in my life would thought it could be done. Why not python? I mean, it's easy throught the Windwos API.

Comment: @AH FYI, I wanted to point out the FREE and install free solution of [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) & it's ability to be robust with emulating mouse clicks & keyboard strokes. It handles the Windows flag key well too & works very reliably in my experience (see some of my written solution here https://superuser.com/search?q=user%3A510662+body%3A+autoit). See the [Send Key list](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm)—this is an easy to learn & use language for automating where batch lacks but you can also use PowerShell & `.Net` coded solutions I suppose.

Comment: It's not free, but I have heard good things about AutoHotKey. I use AutoKey, a similar program on Linux.